# Can't remove intent extra!

Tags: android

I'm creating a notification for the notification tray. I'm specifying a click intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("foo", true);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("" + System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

The MyActivity class gets launched just fine with the "foo" parameter present. However, I cannot get rid of that extra afterwards - it seems to persist in the Intent:

```
// MyActivity
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    // please go away..
    intent.removeExtra("foo");
    getIntent().removeExtra("foo");
}
```

Iterating over the keys of the intent shows that "foo" no longer exists. But if I background the activity, then bring it to the foreground again, the "foo" parameter is present again.

Anyone know how to really get rid of it? I've also tried calling setIntent(), same behavior. It's like the launcher holds onto the original intent and keeps reusing it.

Thanks

Comment: This is one of the silly cases with Java and pointers. You might have to try finalizing the original intent after copying it without foo.

Comment: Ah how does one finalize the original intent, would I do something like call finish() from onNewIntent(), and just relaunch the activity again? I guess the user wouldn't see the sneaky jump, and I'd get rid of that "foo" extra. I think it could work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly what Android is doing. Modifying the intent parameter within the onNewIntent method has no effect on the notification system's stored intent. You should create a new Intent and store that locally in your activity, saving and restoring it like any other data.

EDIT: If you don't need to reuse the intent itself, it would probably make more sense to store the relevant data separately.

Comment: Huh I don't quite follow - do you mean to create a new Intent and call setIntent() with it? (seems to give the same behavior). Otherwise we have to manage this state ourselves I suppose? Thanks

Comment: Oh, are you trying to put the intent back in the notification bar with the extra changed? I think the proper thing to do would be to create a new intent and a new notification.

Comment: Yeah exactly - I want to remove that intent extra, then the next time the user launches from the launcher, I want that extra to be gone. I tried creating a new notification and called setIntent() with it, but same behavior - the "foo" key comes back to torment me.

Comment: Could you get to remove extra?  I couldn't, and ended up using a static boolean flag to indicate if extra is consumed and shouldn't be used again.  I'm very unhappy about this solution!